# PHP image resize with GD use to many CPU time

Tags: php, gd, cpu-usage, image-resizing

I have a script on PHP GD with simple functions how to resize on real-time images on my site, but this process "eat" all my CPU time ... I use VPS with 4 cores and it's not enough.

From image tag i call PHP file (`<img src="image.php?file=XXX&width=XXX&height=XXX" alt="" />`) with image name, new width and new height ... after that in PHP I make this operations:

```
ob_start();

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE^E_DEPRECATED);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $url = $_GET['file'];

    if(!empty($url) && file_exists($url) && is_file($url) && is_readable($url)){
        $width = $_GET['width'];
        $height = $_GET['height'];

        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($url);

        if(empty($width)) $width = $width_orig/($height_orig/$height);
        if(empty($height)) $height = $height_orig/($width_orig/$width);

        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

        if($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
            $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
        } else {
            $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
        }

        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
        imagedestroy($image_p);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }

    ob_end_flush();
```

I don't understand why "eat" to match CPU time ... my original image size it's 1920x2880 px.
How to reduce my CPU usage? Any ideas?

Comment: Cache images so you only do the heavy CPU work once. Use a file system to store the resized image that allows you check if the file has been resized before. Also restrict to certain fixed sizes so you do not have a million little files.

Comment: @Tigger the idea it's not to storage all sizes or 3-4 formats ... i wont to use one image and get image size respect resolution like site of Zara:

https://static.zara.net/photos///2019/V/0/1/p/8246/082/400/3/w/560/8246082400_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1557401940024
or
https://static.zara.net/photos///2019/V/0/1/p/8246/082/400/3/w/960/8246082400_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1557401940024

... it's enough to send different size with "w/1024".

Comment: if you want to constantly resize your images on-the-fly then you have to accept that it's going to be slow...especially when lots of people are using it at once. Graphics transformation is slow, that's just a fact of life. That zara site returns the images so fast it _must_ have cached some of them. Occasionally it takes a little longer to respond, a sign it might be creating the image on the fly since no-one requested that size before. Also it does not let you choose just any size you like - there appear to be upper and lower limits on the width beyond which it will not change.

Comment: All sensible media-heavy sites make extensive use of caching and pre-storage to reduce load on the server. Why transform the image again and again when you already did it once before? The result is the same every time, so what's the point? Make it on the fly the first time someone asks for it, and then keep a copy in case anyone asks for it again. If you use a caching solution, you can also limit the time the files are kept and/or the quantity cached at any time - this can be useful if you need to keep the costs down.